# Is there a special shell command to substitute one character with two inside string in shell script?

Tags: shell, character-encoding

I can not replace the "?" by a number of two digits;
when I try to replace the character "?" with a two-digit number, only prints the first number

I need to print a string with different continuous numbers, which I have been able to do with this line of code;

```
    echo 'my-page-number-?' | tr '?' ${i}
```

But when the number is two digits, then it is cut off;

```
#!/bin/bash
numbers=13

for (( i=1; i <= ${numbers}; ++i ))
do
echo 'my-page-number-?' | tr '?' ${i}
done

my-page-number-1
my-page-number-2
my-page-number-3
my-page-number-4
my-page-number-5
my-page-number-6
my-page-number-7
my-page-number-8
my-page-number-9
my-page-number-10
my-page-number-11
my-page-number-12
my-page-number-13
```

Answer (score 1):

Use printf like so:

```
for (( i=1; i <= ${numbers}; ++i ))
do 
    printf "my-page-number-%02d" $i
done
```

Comment: his example output doesn't include zero paddings. just removing the zero character will display the numbers aligned to the right (or padded with a space character). You can change that by adding a minus after the percent sign: `printf "my-page-number-%-2d" $i`. However, the space padding will be done at the right. Harder to notice, but still there.